# Высота дочернего блока

Tags: css, css3

Как в css сделать так, чтобы высота дочернего блока занимала всю высоту родительского? Высота родительского блока при этом не определена.

Comment: Покажите ваш код

Comment: Это невозможно, ведь высота родительского элемента наоборот зависит от высоты дочернего

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```

А это пример чтобы было понятнее, добавил высоту родителю

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}

.child {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```